# SharePointOnlineCredentials can't find account and

Tags: c#, sharepoint, credentials

I'm trying to connect to my Company's sharepoint but the credentials I use (my email and password) are not recognized and an error is thrown on the `ExecuteQuery` line. Also when I try and get the files using relative paths or url paths, every single property throws a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException`.

```cs
 private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

[FunctionName("SendFiles")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
    ILogger log)
{

    ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/a-b");
    SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
    foreach(char c in "dummypass")
    {
        secureString.AppendChar(c);
    }
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("a.b@faktion.com", secureString);
    Web site = context.Web;

   string jsonInput = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   SendFilesInput input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendFilesInput>(jsonInput);

   string url = "https://a.b.com/gql/api/organisations/" + input.OrganisationId + "/projects/" + input.ProjectId + "/process";
   string response = null;
   bool succesfullRequest = false;
   MultipartFormDataContent formdata = new MultipartFormDataContent();
   try
   {
        foreach (var filePath in input.Files)
        {
            // create filestream content
            var fileurl = "https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/a-b" + "/" + filePath;


            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File temp = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File temp2 = site.GetFileByUrl(fileurl);
            ClientResult<Stream> crstream = temp.OpenBinaryStream();
            ClientResult<Stream> crstream2 = temp2.OpenBinaryStream();
            context.Load(temp);
            context.Load(temp2);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            var tempfile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            if (crstream.Value != null)
            {
                crstream.Value.CopyTo(fs);
            }
            HttpContent content = new StreamContent(fs);
            string name = GetFileName(filePath);
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", GetFileType(name));
            formdata.Add(content, "files", name);
            System.IO.File.Decrypt(tempfile);
        }
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", input.BearerToken);
        // send content to the backend and parse result
        var resultPost = client.PostAsync(url, formdata).Result;
        response = resultPost.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        succesfullRequest = resultPost.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
    // I absolutely want to catch every exception and pass these along to the workflow
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
    // if something went wrong in the backend, throw an error
    if (!succesfullRequest)
    {
         req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Something went wrong during the upload process");
    }
[...] // rest is not important
```

Error:

> The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.

[image: Console Output]

Comment: You are on a Corporate Network where Group Policies are enforced.  Some it is best to check with your MIS people.   I usually first recommend either using a Window Explorer access the files or using a Browser and see if you can access the data.   If you can access the data manually then it is in your application.  if you cannot access the data manually then it is a Group Policy issue.  What Status are you getting in the results (200 OK or something else)?

Comment: The response gives me a 500 Internal Server Error back with the line of: `Value cannot be null` . I'll add a screenshot of the console output.

Comment: You have a syntax error in the POST.  The error message says you need a parameter VALUE which is missing.

Comment: That's what the error says but when I'm debugging, it throws an error on the credentials